# How to get items of web listview kendo ui

Tags: jquery, listview, kendo-ui

I want to know how to get item of listview in kendo ui web.

Here's my code,

```
var listView = $("#listView").data("kendoListView");
var children = listView.items()[1];
children.css({backgroundColor : "green"});
```

When U used var `children = listView.items();` it apply to all `listview`.

How can I make it affect some specific items.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
children.css({backgroundColor : "green"});
```

do

```
$(children).css({ backgroundColor: "red"});
```

Children is an array or HTML elements that do not have a function called `css`. This is a function provided by jQuery so you need to enclose `children` in `$()`.